Google Sheets Web App getActiveUser not working
A web app script I'm using for Google Sheets doesn't seem to be working half the time.
It's a timestamp that should also show the user ID of the editor. But most of the time it works for like a few seconds and then the user ID disappears:
Here's a gif
Same gif via GIPHY
Here's a gist of the script I'm using:
function addTimestamp(e) {

  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();

  if(row >= 5 && col == 2){
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,29).setValue(new Date());
  }

  if(row >= 5 && col == 2){
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,30).setValue(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()); Logger.log(email);
  }

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your current issue, your showing script, and "Google Sheets Web App". Can I ask you about the details of your current issue and your expected result? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Hi Tanaike, thank you for your comment. My current issue is that I can't get getActiveUser to show the user ID permanently (it's part of the timestamp web app that I'm using). In the gif that I included, it shows the user ID for a split second and then it disappears. I want the user ID to show permanently.

May be you got a double function call because reasons that we can't figured out (we don 't know who and how addTimestamp is called) but may be you can replace Logger.log(email); with a something else than "email" that appears to be undefined and log JSON.stringify(e, null, 4) or Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() for instance to check if there is two calls.

Hi jpp, thank you for your comment. I added Logger.log(email) just recently in hopes of fixing the problem. For context, I'd been using this script since before 2020 and it was working fine. There was an update (in 2022 maybe?) that caused this behavior. When I revisited this issue yesterday, I added Logger.log(email) but the result was the same--the user ID appears only for a second.

Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you could forgive my poor English skill.

Panopheles, did you check the log for multiple (unwanted or unexpected) function executions?
(besides: email variable in your code seems not to be initialized !?)

Panopheles, in your gif https://i.sstatic.net/eLDmSZvI.gif i can see in Last Action column somethin that is not just a date "by Jemma" but in your code where you add the date you dont add anything more than the date !?
.getRange(row,29).setValue(new Date());
Are you sure that there is no other code writing in that cell?

Hi jpp, thanks for the follow-up. Oh, the Last Action column is just concatenate: =IF(AC5="","", CONCATENATE(TEXT(AC5, "d-mmm-yyyy, DDD"), ", at ", TEXT(AC5, "H:MM:SSA/P"),AB5))

I see.
two questions:
a) do you know from where exactly "by Jemma" stirng is coming (where is generated)?
2) does the log in the addTimestamp report any unexpected call?

Jpp, it's generated by this:
if(row >= 5 && col == 2){
e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,30).setValue(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()); Logger.log(email);
}
The results are the same with or without Logger.log(email)

Panopheles, as i see in the line you mention, email value is not set, so you can't log it.
I think "by Jemma" is not a possible result of getEmail method, so both previous questions still stand.
